# Carousel autoplay video

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, video

I have a carousel with images and videos and I decided to play the videos automatically. The problem is that when I load the page that contain the carousel, it automatically reproduces the video. I need  to play the video automatically when I positioned on its corresponding slide. The problem is that I don't know how to do it.

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                @{bool Active = true;}
                @foreach (var item in Model.ListImage)
                {
                    <div class="item @(Activo ? "active" : "")">
                        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="/content/images/@(item.File)" alt="">
                    </div>

                    Active = false;

                }
                @foreach (var item in Model.ListVideo)
                {
                    <div class="item" style="text-align: center;">
                        <video style="margin-bottom: 100px;" width="auto" height="500px" controls autoplay>
                            <source src="/content/images/@(item.File)" type="video/mp4">
                        </video>
                    </div>

                }

            </div>


                <!-- Controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev" ">
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next" ">
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>

        </div
```

Comment: What library are you using to make this carousel? Or it's custom made?

Comment: im using bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the lib that you using for the carousel, but you have to remove the autoplay attribute of all videos and add it when the current slide is showed only.

Probably you have a callback on your carousel to change the current slide after it's showed.

EDIT:

I look about the bootstrap carousel and you can use this event:

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () { // function called when the slide is showed
  $('.item video').removeAttr('autoplay'); // To stop all videos
  $('.item.active video').attr('autoplay', 'autoplay'); // To play the current video
});
```

Comment: I added the code that you can use to stop and play the videos.